# SIRI is not speaking back based on parameters supplied, instead opens "Shortcut" app

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts

Im working with SiriKit to check for details in my app. I have used Coredata to pass data between app and extension. Its all working fine.

My issue is, based on my parameter passed to CustomIntentHandler class -> resolveParameterName method(default method created by system), like ".disambiguation(with: ["one, two"])" or "INStringResolutionResult.needsValue()" opens shortcuts app. 
I want SIRI to interact with me and get details and process.

Please help me in solving.

Comment: Have you tested in the physical device? The simulator has limited capabilities for the extensions.

Comment: Yes, it checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with iOS 13, and got resolved in iOS 13.1.2.

Now SIRI is all working like champ.